# How to create a dynamic select list with multiselect as the last select box, only using html and js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tailwind-css

It's about a course selection. First we select the course, depending on that we select the level and then a batch as given in the code. but finally I want to select either 1 or more subjects inluding all subjects which selects all the given subjects I also want to pass these data as a form to the backend. so I need values and names to include in each input

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">  <head>     <meta charset="UTF-8">     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">     <link rel="stylesheet" href="output.css">     <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />     <title>Document</title> </head>  <body class="bg-[#FFF4C4] dark:bg-gray-900 ">     <section>         <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:my-24 md:h-screen lg:py-0">             <!-- centering -->             <div                 class="w-full bg-white shadow-md rounded-2xl dark:border md:mt-0 md:max-w-4xl xl:p-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">                 <!-- content -->                 <div class="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-1 sm:p-6">                     <!-- padding inside -->                     <h1                         class="h-10 text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-2xl dark:text-white">                         Course Registration                     </h1>                       <div class="grid grid-cols-none gap-4 p md:grid-cols-2">                         <div>                             <div>                                 <form class="max-w-sm mx-auto">                                     <label class="block mb-2 text-base font-medium text-black dark:text-white">Select a                                         course</label>                                     <select                                         class="block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 text-base text-gray-900 border border-yellow-300 rounded-lg shadow-xl bg-gray-50 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 disabled:opacity-30 disabled:border-none"                                         id="course">                                         <option selected >Choose a course</option>                                     </select>                                      <label class="block mb-2 text-base font-medium text-black dark:text-white">Select a                                         level(s)</label>                                     <select                                         class="block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 text-base text-gray-900 border border-yellow-300 rounded-lg shadow-xl disabled:opacity-30 disabled:border-none bg-gray-50 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 "                                         id="level">                                         <option selected >Choose a level</option>                                     </select>                                      <label class="block mb-2 text-base font-medium text-black dark:text-white">Select a                                         batch</label>                                     <select                                         class="block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 text-base text-gray-900 border border-yellow-300 rounded-lg shadow-xl disabled:opacity-30 disabled:border-none bg-gray-50 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 "                                         id="batch">                                         <option selected >Choose a batch</option>                                     </select>                                      <label class="block mb-2 text-base font-medium text-black dark:text-white">Select                                         subject(s)</label>                                     <select                                         class="block w-full px-4 py-3 mb-4 text-base text-gray-900 border border-yellow-300 rounded-lg shadow-xl disabled:opacity-30 disabled:border-none bg-gray-50 focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 "                                         id="subject">                                         <option selected >Choose a subject</option>                                     </select>                                 </form>                             </div>                             <div>                                 <button id="dropdownCheckboxButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownDefaultCheckbox"                                     class="text-black bg-yellow-300 hover:bg-red-500 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"                                     type="button">Select Course <svg class="w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-3" aria-hidden="true"                                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">                                         <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"                                             stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4" />                                     </svg>                                 </button>                                  <!-- Dropdown menu -->                                 <div id="dropdownDefaultCheckbox"                                     class="z-10 hidden w-48 bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600">                                     <ul class="p-3 space-y-3 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200"                                         aria-labelledby="dropdownCheckboxButton">                                         <li>                                             <div class="flex items-center">                                                 <input id="checkbox-item-1" type="checkbox" value=""                                                     class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-700 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500">                                                 <label for="checkbox-item-1"                                                     class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ms-2 dark:text-gray-300">Default                                                     checkbox</label>                                             </div>                                         </li>                                         <li>                                             <div class="flex items-center">                                                 <input checked id="checkbox-item-2" type="checkbox" value=""                                                     class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-700 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500">                                                 <label for="checkbox-item-2"                                                     class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ms-2 dark:text-gray-300">Checked                                                     state</label>                                             </div>                                         </li>                                         <li>                                             <div class="flex items-center">                                                 <input id="checkbox-item-3" type="checkbox" value=""                                                     class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-offset-gray-700 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500">                                                 <label for="checkbox-item-3"                                                     class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ms-2 dark:text-gray-300">Default                                                     checkbox</label>                                             </div>                                         </li>                                     </ul>                                 </div>                             </div>                          </div>                     </div>                 </div>             </div>         </div>         </div>         </div>     </section>      <script src="../node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>     <script src="select.js"></script>     <!-- <script src="try.js"></script> --> </body>  </html>
```

**JS code**

```
var CourseLevelBatchSubject = {
  BIT: {
    "Full Degree": {
      "Batch 501": ["All subjects"],
    },
    "Semester 1": {
      "Batch 501": ["IM", "IS", "CS", "PC", "Programming", "All subjects"],
    },
    "Semester 2": {
      "Batch 601": ["Com 1", "MC", "SE", "DB", "WAD 1", "All subjects"],
    },
    "Semester 3": {
      "Batch 701": ["Com 2", "OOAD", "DSA", "DMS", "WAD 2", "All subjects"],
    },
    "Semester 4": {
      Batch: ["UED", "EAD", "ITPM", "ASD", "CN", "All subjects"],
    },
    "Semester 5": {
      Batch: ["FME", "SDP", "PP", "PIS", "SNA", "MC 2", "All subjects"],
    },
    "Semester 6": {
      Batch: ["ETIS", "SQA", "MAD", "NSA", "EBT", "All subjects"],
    },
    "Semester 2 to 6": { Batch: ["All subjects"] },
    "Semester 3 to 6": { Batch: ["All subjects"] },
    "Semester 4 to 6": { Batch: ["All subjects"] },
    "Semester 5 to 6": { Batch: ["All subjects"] },
    Project: { Batch: ["No subjects (Only project)"] },
  },
  BCS: {
    "All levels": {},
    "Certificate Level": {},
    "Diploma Level": {},
    "PGD in IT": {},
    Project: {},
  },
  FIT: {},
};

window.onload = function () {
  const selectcourse = document.getElementById("course"),
    selectlevel = document.getElementById("level"),
    selectbatch = document.getElementById("batch"),
    selectsubject = document.getElementById("subject"),
    selects = document.querySelectorAll("select");

  selectlevel.disabled = true;
  selectbatch.disabled = true;
  selectsubject.disabled = true;

  selects.forEach((select) => {
    if (select.disabled == true) {
      select.style.cursor = "auto";
    } else {
      select.style.cursor = "pointer";
    }
  });

  for (let course in CourseLevelBatchSubject) {
    selectcourse.options[selectcourse.options.length] = new Option(
      course,
      course
    );
  }
  // select course
  selectcourse.onchange = (e) => {
    selectlevel.disabled = false;
    selectbatch.disabled = true;
    selectsubject.disabled = true;

    selectlevel.length = 1;
    selectbatch.length = 1;
    selectsubject.length = 1;

    for (let level in CourseLevelBatchSubject[e.target.value]) {
      selectlevel.options[selectlevel.options.length] = new Option(
        level,
        level
      );
    }
  };

  // select level
  selectlevel.onchange = (e) => {
    selectbatch.disabled = false;
    selectsubject.disabled = true;

    selectbatch.length = 1;
    selectsubject.length = 2;

    for (let batch in CourseLevelBatchSubject[selectcourse.value][
      e.target.value
    ]) {
      selectbatch.options[selectbatch.options.length] = new Option(
        batch,
        batch
      );
    }
  };

  //change batch
  selectbatch.onchange = (e) => {
    selectsubject.disabled = false;

    selectsubject.length = 1;

    let subjects =
      CourseLevelBatchSubject[selectcourse.value][selectlevel.value][
        e.target.value
      ];
    for (let i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
      selectsubject.options[selectsubject.options.length] = new Option(
        subjects[i],
        subjects[i]
      );
    }
  };
};
```

I have used tailwind with flowbite component. It's fine if u don't use any styling. I only want the code itself